# mysql query error in where statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my query correct in phmyadmin before using it in my code and i get the following error, although i know the column exists

```
Error
SQL query:


UPDATE 
tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product 
SET 
tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity
WHERE 
tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id

MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Do you really have a column named `euid0_hikashop_product.product_id`?

Comment: yes (database)tendesig_zink_production.(table)euid0_hikashop_product.(column)product_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an unknown column error is because your query does not know about the table `tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product`. Try using this query

```
UPDATE 
tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product, tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product
SET 
tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_quantity
WHERE 
tendesig_zink_dev.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id = tendesig_zink_production.euid0_hikashop_product.product_id
```